# Given that $\cos a= 24/25$ and $\sin a<0$, find $\cos(a+\pi/6)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Given that  $\cos a= 24/25$ and $\sin a<0$, find  $\cos(a+\pi/6)$

I graphed $24/25$ in the $4$th quadrant and then did Pythagorean theorem. After that I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

$$\implies\sin A=-\sqrt{1-\cos^2A}=\cdots$$

I think you have meant $\cos\left(A+\dfrac\pi6\right)$

then,
$$\cos\left(A+\frac\pi6\right)=\cos A\cdot\cos\frac\pi6-\sin A\cdot\sin\frac\pi6$$

Comment: What would you get after doing the math?

Comment: @DhondupTenzing, Not sure if I understood you correctly?

Comment: I got it thanks

Comment: @DhondupTenzing, Please clarify your first statement

Answer (score 0):

Since @lab-bhattacharjee gived an formular answer (we gonna solve later) - I am gonna show you geometrical:

I. How to construct an $\frac\pi6$ angle:
[image]

II. I made a $5$ (units) scale and use a compass to do into $25$. I won the value $24$ via  [intercept theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem)
[image]
Now: My geometrical solution ends on $24<x_2<25\rightarrow x_2=r\cdot cos(a+\frac\pi6)$ where $r=25$ .

Thus:
$$
x_2=25\cdot[\cos a\cdot\cos\frac\pi6-\sin a\cdot\sin\frac\pi6]
$$
$$
x_2=25\cdot[\cos a\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3}}2-(-\sqrt{1-cos^2a})\cdot\frac12]
$$
$$
x_2=25\cdot[\frac{24}{25}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3}}2+\sqrt{1-\frac{576}{625}}\cdot\frac12]=25\cdot[\frac{24}{25}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3}}2+\sqrt{\frac{49}{625}}\cdot\frac12]
$$
$$
x_2=25\cdot[\frac{24}{25}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3}}2+\frac{7}{25}\cdot\frac12]
$$
$$
x_2=24\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3}}2+\frac72\approx20.785+3.5\approx24.285
$$
Conclusion: My geometrical way is **right**.